# Error using vl_nnconv Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options

Tags: matlab, neural-network, convolution, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

I'm trying to tune a pretrained VGG Convolutional Neural Networks Practical (2) network I downloaded from http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/ .
When I execute the exercise 3 this error appears. I did not understand why.

Comment: It's not very clear which exercise are you trying to do. However the out-of-memory error means that your RAM is full and the program cannot continue. You should check your variables in your Workspace, try removing from the Workspace variables you don't use. Also try closing programs and applications you don't need. This will also free some RAM.

Comment: thanks Alessiox , it means that the error commen from espace in memory and not from the function

Comment: Indeed. The out-of-memory error is an error related to the available RAM memory vs the memory requested by your code. If your code needs a lot of memory but your RAM cannot satisfy its requirements, Matlab will throw the out-of-memory error.

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation for the memory function, for example a 32 bit version of matlab can't address the full memory of a typical pc. In such cases it might be possible to solve without buying additional memory.

Comment: how resolve this problem , my machin is 32bit

Comment: assuming your 32 bit machine can address all your memory (most likely), you need more ram or you can increase the page file size (virtual memory). 2nd option will make things run a lot slower if you actually need a lot more ram

Comment: @hiandbaii, increasing the swap memory is actually a very valid idea. Didn't came to mind. The OP can find some good resources here http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html#brh72ex-54 and here https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_increase_MATLABs_memory

Comment: thanks but the problem still

Comment: @Khouloud: Did you identify the issue using `memory`? Did you really run out of memory or is the address space exceeded? Did you successfully increase the pagefile? If you have problems understanding any of the comments ask for additional explanations.